# Зачем нужно поле повторного пароля при регистрации?

Tags: javascript, html, input, password

[image: input pass]

Подскажите, зачем нужно поле подтверждения пароля в формах регистрации? Нужно ли ему тоже присваивать атрибут `name` и его значение отправлять на сервер ?
*Не надо, пожалуйста в ответах, писать что оно не надо... без вас начитался статей, где его ругают.
Меня интересует, зачем оно вообще было придумано ?

Comment: Наверное чтоб дать пользователю шанс проверить точно, что он не опечатался  в пароле и правильно его записал)

Comment: Мне больше интересно, зачем повтор email делают)

Comment: @OliverPatterson мне больше интересно, почему если поторы для паролей и email'ов делают, чтоб дать юзеру шанс убедиться, что всё он ввёл без ошибок, то почему нет двух полей логинов :D :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень кратко <strike>пофилософствуем</strike> поразмышляем.

> Подскажите, зачем нужно поле подтверждения пароля в формах регистрации?
> Меня интересует, зачем оно вообще было придумано?

Дополнительное второе поле для ввода пароля в формах регистрации для <strike>его подтверждения</strike> того, чтобы *подтвердить совпадение с введенным паролем в первом поле*, было придумано лишь с одной целью, а именно — исключить человеческий фактор ошибки при вводе пароля. Эта ошибка — простая оплошность, опечатка. Вызвана такая ошибка может быть лишь по той причине, что как правило, поле для пароля отличается от остальных тем, что все вводимые символы отображаются звездочками, точками или другими знаками (в зависимости от браузера). Итак, если при вводе оба пароля совпадают, то это подразумевает собой то, что пользователь осознанно и безошибочно ввел свой пароль, и в дальнейшем при авторизации он не получит отказ в доступе.

> Нужно ли ему тоже присваивать атрибут name и его значение отправлять
> на сервер?

Атрибут `name`, как мы знаем, определяет уникальное имя элемента формы, и как правило, это имя используется при отправке данных на сервер или для доступа к введенным данным поля через скрипты. Ответ на вопрос — нет. Потому что:

1. На сервер чаще всего отправляется один пароль (значение). Поэтому, атрибут `name` мы применяем только к одному элементу формы.
2. Для доступа к введенным данным через скрипты нам совсем не обязательно нужен атрибут `name`. Мы можем каждому тегу `input` задать уникальное имя элемента (`id` — стилевой идентификатор), и через него обращаться к элементу. Например:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {$("#p1, #p2").keyup(validate);});

function validate() {
  var pass1 = $("#p1").val();
  var pass2 = $("#p2").val();

  if (pass1 == pass2) {$("#valid").text("Пароли совпадают");
  } else {$("#valid").text("Пароли не совпадают");}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" method="post">
  <input id="p1" type="password" placeholder="пароль">
  <input id="p2" type="password" name="password" placeholder="пароль еще раз">
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
<p id="valid"></p>
```

---

> *Мне больше интересно, зачем повтор email делают)* – [Oliver Patterson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266072/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#comment2226651_1266072)

Ровно по той же причине.

Да, конечно, кому-то это (подтверждение введенных данных) может показаться забавным. Однако, нужно признать, что иногда такой функционал порой оказывается своевременно полезным. Полезен, например, для более старшего возрастного контингента пользователей сети, да и не только.

---

**Помните!** Храните свои пароли и личные данные в безопасном месте — на бумаге. Все, что связано с компьютерами и электронными носителями, подразумевает собой высокий риск несанкционированного доступа третьих лиц. Хранить личные данные на локальных носителях — не самое разумное решение. Опытному <strike>хакеру</strike> профессионалу не составит большого труда достать ваши данные из вашего персонального компьютера или телефона. Всегда помните об этом.

Comment: "Храните свои пароли и личные данные в безопасном месте — на бумаге" 
 ---  https://nag.ru/upload2/623566533.jpeg   , https://habrastorage.org/storage2/e26/9c4/2c8/e269c42c8760bc2190ebafcc7539b147.jpg   :)))

Comment: В проверках паролей практически всегда забывают о том, что существуют другие языки на клавиатуре, и я часто ввожу Password как Зфыыцщкв. Но проверка при этом показывает, что первый пароль соответствует второму и вы проходите во второй раунд.